# How to aggregate counts across values in a PySpark array

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark array that maps customers to a list of categories as well as a geo location.

```
[('customer', 'bigint'), ('category', 'array<int>'), ('geo_location', 'string')]
```

Each customer can map to more than one category so I capture it as a list.

I'd like to count up the number of customers in each category while preserving the geo information.

Is there a method in pyspark that will easily unpack the list values as a column so I can count them?  Alternatively, is there a better pattern in PySpark that will accomplish this in a better way?

Comment: Are you able to put in a sample data and expected output?

Comment: https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-explode-array-and-map-columns-to-rows/ maybe you can use explode If I understood it right

Comment: Explode was the right way to do it.  If you post an answer I'll accept it.